# htaccess : access non www domain is showing index.php in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried every configuration possible but I just cant make it working.
I know the topic has come up number of times but I can't get the right solution for my case though it should be pretty simple.

When accessing `www.example.fr`, everything works fine and I get redirected to https://www.example.fr.

Now if I access `example.fr` then I get redirected to https://www.example.fr/index.php.
I also just noticed that if I access https://www.example.com (same domain, different extension that belongs to me) I get redirected to https://www.example.com/index.php

Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.fr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

I want to get rid of that `/index.php` forever.
Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must place redirects before rewrites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.fr%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Oh thanks, notification didnt show up, I will try that and tell you, but I actually finally managed to find a way out !

Comment: Thanks, I went back to this problem, I had to fix some other issues but now its all good, thanks for reminding me the right order it should be. I may have one more question, about redirection still, I may hit you up later !

Comment: Oh, btw, I got it to work but I forgot to tell you one thing : if the 'index.php' is in the URL (like, if I add it manually) it won't get removed (but all my redirections are working fine). Is that the expected behaviour ? I was so concerned about the redirections that I forgot the main part ahah. Therefore as said in my first comment, I managed to get rid of it by adding :

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) / [R=301,NE,L]

Otherwise it remains here... I'm lost now ahah !

Comment: Yes, you have to do that to get rid of index.php